# namenode, datanode not list by using jps

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

Environment: ubuntu 14.04, hadoop 2.6

After I type the `start-all.sh` and `jps`, `DataNode` doesn't list on the terminal

```
>jps
9529 ResourceManager
9652 NodeManager
9060 NameNode
10108 Jps
9384 SecondaryNameNode
```

according to this answer : [Datanode process not running in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889261/datanode-process-not-running-in-hadoop)

I try its best solution

- `bin/stop-all.sh (or stop-dfs.sh and stop-yarn.sh in the 2.x serie)`
- `rm -Rf /app/tmp/hadoop-your-username/*`
- `bin/hadoop namenode -format (or hdfs in the 2.x series)`

However, now I get this:

```
>jps
20369 ResourceManager
26032 Jps
20204 SecondaryNameNode
20710 NodeManager
```

As you can see, even the `NameNode` is missing, please help me.

`DataNode logs` : https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/b561bbd9cdcb9bf36032

`NmaeNode logs` : https://gist.github.com/fifiteen82726/02dcf095b5a23c1570b0

`mapred-site.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

### UPDATE

```
coda@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/04/30 01:07:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
coda@localhost's password: 
localhost: chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Operation not permitted
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.4’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.5’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.3’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.4’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.2’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.3’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.1’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.2’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out.1’: Permission denied
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
localhost: ulimit -a for user coda
localhost: core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
localhost: data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
localhost: scheduling priority             (-e) 0
localhost: file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
localhost: pending signals                 (-i) 3877
localhost: max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
localhost: max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
localhost: open files                      (-n) 1024
localhost: pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-namenode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
coda@localhost's password: 
localhost: chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Operation not permitted
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.4’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.5’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.3’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.4’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.2’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.3’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.1’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.2’: Permission denied
localhost: mv: cannot move ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out’ to ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out.1’: Permission denied
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 159: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
localhost: ulimit -a for user coda
localhost: core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
localhost: data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
localhost: scheduling priority             (-e) 0
localhost: file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
localhost: pending signals                 (-i) 3877
localhost: max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
localhost: max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
localhost: open files                      (-n) 1024
localhost: pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 177: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 178: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-coda-datanode-ubuntu.out: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
coda@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Operation not permitted
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 20204. Stop it first.
15/04/30 01:07:51 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Operation not permitted
resourcemanager running as process 20369. Stop it first.
coda@localhost's password: 
localhost: chown: changing ownership of ‘/usr/local/hadoop/logs’: Operation not permitted
localhost: nodemanager running as process 20710. Stop it first.
coda@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
20369 ResourceManager
2934 Jps
20204 SecondaryNameNode
20710 NodeManager
```

### UPDATE

```
hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ $HADOOP_HOME ./start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
15/05/03 09:32:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-ubuntu.out
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: datanode running as process 28584. Stop it first.
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
hadoop@0.0.0.0's password: 
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-ubuntu.out
15/05/03 09:32:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-ubuntu.out
hadoop@localhost's password: 
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-ubuntu.out
hadoop@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
6842 Jps
28584 DataNode
```

Comment: could you please update the namenode logs ?

Comment: Post your datanode logs too.

Comment: actually you should not format your namenode more than once, Now your cluster is unstable because of this..

Comment: Sorry for asking a silly question, how to find NameNode, DataNode logs?

Comment: You can find hadoop logs in `$HADOOP_HOME/logs` folder.

Comment: Thx, I already posted DataNode and NameNode logs link.

Comment: could you post your mapred-site.xml?

Comment: already posted^^, thanks

Comment: Should I just reinstall the whole system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
>   java.io.IOException: All directories in dfs.datanode.data.dir are invalid: **"/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/"**

This error may be due to wrong permissions for `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/` folder.

> FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: Directory **/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode** is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

This error may be due to wrong permissions for `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/namenode` folder or it does not exist. To rectify this problem follow these options:

**OPTION I:**

If you don't have the folder `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs`, then create and give permission to the folder as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs
sudo chown -R hadoopuser:hadoopgroup /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs
```

Change `hadoopuser` and `hadoopgroup` to your hadoop username and hadoop groupname respectively. Now, try to start the hadoop processes. If the problem still persists, try option 2.

**OPTION II:**

Remove the contents of `/usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs` folder:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/*
```

Change folder permission:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs
```

Now, start the hadoop processes. It should work.

> **NOTE: Post the new logs if error persists.**

**UPDATE:**

In case you haven't created the hadoop user and group, do it as follows:

```
sudo addgroup hadoop
sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hadoop
```

Now, change ownership of `/usr/local/hadoop` and `/usr/local/hadoop_store`:

```
sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop
sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop /usr/local/hadoop_store
```

Change your user to hadoop:

```
su - hadoop
```

Enter your hadoop user password. Now your terminal should be like:

`hadoop@ubuntu:$`

Now, type:

`$HADOOP_HOME/bin/start-all.sh`

or

`sh /usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh`

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local` results?

Comment: What does `whoami` in terminal results?

Comment: Did you do these steps while installing hadoop: `sudo addgroup hadoopgroupname` and `sudo adduser --ingroup hadoopgroupname hadoopusername`?. The `hadoopgroupname` and `hadoopusername` you have given while installing will be your hadoop groupname and username respectively.

Comment: `whoami` show my username : `coda` , I didn't type `sudo adduser --ingroup hadoopgroupname hadoopusername` while installing hadoop. Is that the reason I fail?

Comment: Updated answer. Look into it.

Comment: I do what you said, `sudo addgroup hadoop` and` sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hadoop`, then I `stat-all.sh` , it still didn't run `datanode` and`namenode`.  So I try your `option1` and `option2` and I also change the`hadoopuser:hadoopgroup` to `hadoop:hadoop`, it didn't work either. I post the error message after typing `start-all.sh`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76610/discussion-between-coda-chang-and-rajesh-n).

Comment: You have to run `start-all.sh` as hadoop user and not as coda user. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I did what you said and tried for a long time, but I still can not figure it out. This time, the `DataNode` is working but others died. I have posted new error messages.

Comment: Post your other logs. Also, try to stop all process first and then start it again.

Comment: I stop all process, and it work.Thanks, you are a genius. Thx for helping me so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can give you only one Up-vote - its such an awesome answer.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the similar problem, `jps` was **not** showing datanode.

Removing the content of `hdfs` folder and changing folder permission worked out for me.

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs/*
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs    
hadoop namenode =format
start-all.sh
jps
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember when setting up the permission:----
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
The above command should be entered in namenode only.
and then the generated public key should be added to all data node 
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 
and then press the command
ssh 
permission will set ......
after that no password will require at the time of starting dfs......

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem: Namenode service not showing in Jps command
Solution: Its due to permission problem with directory /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs 
just change the permission and format namenode and restart the hadoop:

$sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/hadoop_store/hdfs

$hadoop namenode -format

$start-all.sh

$jps

Answer (score 0):

Solution is first stop your namenode using
go to your /usr/local/hadoop

`bin/hdfs namenode -format`

then delete hdfs and tmp directory from your home

```
mkdir ~/tmp
mkdir ~/hdfs
chmod 750 ~/hdfs
```

goto hadoop directory and start hadoop

```
`sbin/start-dfs.sh`
```

it will show the datanode

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to give permission to you hdfc folder.
Then run below commands:

1. create a group by command: `sudo adgroup hadoop`
2. add ur user into this: `sudo usermod -a -G hadoop "ur_user"` 
   ( u can see current user by Who command)
3. Now change the owner ship of this hadoop_store directly by: 
   `sudo chown -R "ur_user":"ur_gourp" /usr/local/hadoop_store`
4. then format name node again by: 
   `hdfs namenode -format`

and start all services you can see the result.....now type JPS (it will work).