# How to start datanode in hadoop slave machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cluster-computing

I'm creating hadoop cluster using yarn configuration, i have 2 VMs from virtual box, but when i run the command `start-all.sh` (start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh), i get a possitive anwser with `jps` both on master and slave terminal, but when i access master-ip:9870 on web there is no datanode started

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/data/nameNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoopuser/hadoop/data/dataNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
        <value>HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>hadoop-master</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

workers

```
hadoop-slave1
```

/etc/hosts

```
master-ip    hadoop-master
slave-ip     hadoop-slave1
```

The configuration above is in both master and slave machine.

I also have the `JAVA_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` and `PDSH_RCMD_TYPE` in my .bashrc. And i have created the ssh key in master and shared it with the slave authorized for allows ssh connection.

In master machine i have this output:

[image]

In my slave machine:

[image]

I have 0 nodes in my hdfs web visualization:

[image]

But i can see the slave node in yarn configuration:

[image]

I deleted hadoop tmp files and the datanode folders before format my hdfs on master, and start all processes. I'm using hadoop 3.2.1

Comment: Have you tried copying some files into HDFS ?

Comment: yes, i received a error like `There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation`

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924256/4326922

Comment: i did this process, before and nothing